# Not to execute some part of code in objective-c based on flag

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have some code used in side project that i don't want execute at this moment.
Also i don't want to remove it or comment it out everywhere for time being.

Is there any way available? So i can make it executable or not executable based on my requirement.

For ex. you have a huge project like facebook app, where at last moment of production release , you find one bug and in current release you don't want to execute some portion of code which is being used many place in side your project.

Comment: That's probably not what you want but I'd like to suggest using VCS for that kind of situations :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put `if` or even `else`:

```
if(yourCondition){
    //execute these parts only when the above 'yourCondition' satisfies
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

As you said it is a bad practice to put if-else.

Then you can go with this way (as Apple does):

By using `#if, #else, #endif`

One such example from `NSView.h` is :

```
#if MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_6
enum {
    NSViewLayerContentsPlacementScaleAxesIndependently      =  0,
    ....
    NSViewLayerContentsPlacementTopLeft                     = 11
};
#endif
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but i don't think it is a standard practice to put a lots of if...else block inside your code.

Comment: just take an example few features are there in 10.9 which are not in 10.8 then we need to use if-else to check and do that way.  Also `#ifdef` and `#ifndef` are used for this throughout.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with macros. Wrap your code under macro condition,

```
#ifdef EXECUTE
  //Code
#endif
```

Then if you want this code to be executed, just define the macro as `#define EXECUTE`. If code is not to be executed then do not define or comment out the `#define` statement.

Advantage of using this over `if-else` checks in code is, these provide conditional compilation, that is, code wrapped inside the condition will not be included in the binary if the condition is not defined.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the unwanted portion with `#ifdef` and `#endif`. Then go to your `Build Settings` of your target, find `Preprocessor Macros`, define your variable for only `Debug` mode. Now, unwanted portion will be executed only for `Debug` builds, `Release` builds do not have that portion of code.